# How to improve MTKView rendering when using MPSImageScale and MTLBlitCommandEncoder

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit

TL;DR: From within my `MTKView`'s delegate `drawInMTKView:` method, part of my rendering pass involves adding an `MPSImageBilinearScale` performance shader and zero or more `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` requests for `generateMipmapsForTexture`. Is that a smart thing to do from within `drawInMTKView:`, which happens on the main thread? Do either of them block the main thread while running or are they only being encoded and then executed later and entirely on the GPU?

**Longer Version:**

I'm playing around with Metal within the context of an imaging application. I use Core Image to load an image and apply filters. The output image is displayed as a 2D plane in a metal view with a single texture. This works, but to improve performance I wanted to experiment with Core Image's ability to render out smaller tiles at a time. Each tile is rendered into its own `IOSurface`.

On each render pass, I check if there are any tiles that have been recently rendered. For each rendered tile (which is now an `IOSurface`), I create a Metal texture from a `CVMetalTextureCache` that is backed by the surface.

I think use a scaling `MPS` to copy from the tile-texture into the "master" texture. If a tile was copied over, then I issue a blit command to generate the mipmaps on the master texture.

What I'm seeing is that if my master texture is quite large, then generate the mipmaps can take "a bit of time". The same is true if I have a lot of tiles. *It appears* this is blocking the main thread because my FPS drops significantly. (The `MTKView` is running at the standard 60fps.)

If I play around with tile sizes, then I can improve performance in some areas but decrease it in others. For example, increasing the tile size that Core Image renders it creates less tiles, and thus less calls to generate mipmaps and blits, but at the cost of Core Image taking longer to render a region.

If I decrease the size of my "master" texture, then mipmap generation goes faster since only the dirty textures are updates, but there appears to be a lower bounds on how small I should make the master texture because if I make it too small, then I need to pass in a large number of textures to the fragment shader. (And it looks like that limit might be 128?)

What's not entirely clear to me is how much of this I can move off the main thread while still using MTKView. If part of the rendering pass is going to block the main thread, then I'd prefer to move it to a background through so that UI elements (like sliders and checkboxes) remain fully responsive.

Or maybe this isn't the right strategy in the first place? Is there a better way to display really large images in Metal other than tiling? (i.e.: Images larger than Metal's texture size limit of 16384?)